# How to apply equinox p2 to an RCP application containing DLLs

Tags: eclipse-rcp, auto-update, equinox, p2

I'm trying to implement the p2 update mechanism into an RCP application that contains DLLs (integrated via JNI). The whole RCP application (including these DLLs) has to be kept up to date.

Currently the PDE build is not aware of the DLLs - make/gcc generates and copies them into the delivery in the end.

How to make p2 aware of the DLLs? They have to be added to the p2 repository and p2 within the RCP application has to update them, when newer versions are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the DLLs in your plugin.

After you have gnerated them, copy them into a folder in your plugin project. Then add the folder containing the DLLs to the Binary Build section in your plugin.xml editor. You can make the plugin aware of the DLLS using the `Bundle-NativeCode:` entry in the Mainfest.mf of the plugin. This way the DLLs are included inside your plugin's jar and are therefore automatically included in your p2 repository.